# Fatal error: Class 't3lib_pageSelect' not found in Typo3 7.5

Tags: migration, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-7.x

I want to migrate an extension from Typo3 6.2 to Typo3 7.5 In Typo3 6.2 it works fine but in the Typo3 7.5 I get the following error:

`Fatal error: Class 't3lib_pageSelect' not found in ...`

It think that its not anymore supported, but when I'm right what I must use now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. In Typo3 7.x there is no support for the old classes anymore. Instead of `t3lib_pageSelect` I must use the new class with namespace: `\TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Page\PageRepository`.

So for my case I want to read the Typo3 cache and know I must use

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Page\PageRepository::getHash(md5Hash)
```

An in the case of save the cache I must use

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Page\PageRepository::storeHash(md5Hash, data as a string,'NAME')
```

Thats the new one for the old class `t3lib_pageSelect`.

Comment: The old classes can be used with extension "compatibility6"
http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/compatibility6
But this is not recommended.